# What is default executablePath in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

This initialization works well even if we are not passing [`executablePath`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions.executablepath) in [`LaunchOptions`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions) in [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.puppeteernode.launch/)

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
```

What is default value of `executablePath`?

Comment: Near-dupe of [How to find which chrome executable is getting used by Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888444/how-to-find-which-chrome-executable-is-getting-used-by-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0):

The path will change based on the platform that you install puppeteer on.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer/src/node/install.ts
has methods for finding that path.