# How to find which chrome executable is getting used by Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, executable-path

```js
// executablePath is specified
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/path/to/chrome'
});

// // executablePath is not specified
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
// This will not work. 
// console.log('executablePath is', browser.executablePath)
```

If we do not specify a value for the executablePath option, [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) will try to find the default installation of Chrome or Chromium on the system. On Windows, this is usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe. On macOS and Linux, Puppeteer will try to use the chrome or chromium executable in the PATH.

How we can find out which executable is getting used by Puppetter in Puppeteer script itself?

Comment: Near-dupe of [What is default executablePath in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888281/what-is-default-executablepath-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1):

https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.puppeteernode.executablepath

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
console.log(puppeteer.executablePath())
```

Example output on my node-18 docker image is

```bash
root@021100c40ec4:/usr/src/app# node -e "console.log(require('puppeteer').executablePath())"
/root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1069273/chrome-linux/chrome
```